# How to retrieve keys and values from syslogs?

Tags: regex, linux

I'm trying to parse logs from syslog but i'm having some doubts and difficulties find a proper regex formula for this.

Here below some sample logs, in particular i need to retrieve for each line the values for POWER, LoadAvg, etc...

```
2019-08-20T00:26:39.146778+02:00 4CHdoorManager ESP-RSL: SENSOR = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:39","AM2301":{"Temperature":null,"Humidity":null},"TempUnit":"C"}
2019-08-20T00:26:40.473409+02:00 BedroomBlind ESP-RSL: STATE = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:40","Uptime":"0T10:19:02","Vcc":3.116,"SleepMode":"Dynamic","Sleep":50,"LoadAvg":19,"POWER1":"OFF","POWER2":"OFF","Wifi":{"AP":1,"SSId":"*************","BSSId":"*************","Channel":11,"RSSI":60,"LinkCount":1,"Downtime":"0T00:00:06"}}
2019-08-20T00:26:43.669180+02:00 KitchenLight ESP-RSL: STATE = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:44","Uptime":"3T10:54:22","Heap":15,"SleepMode":"Dynamic","Sleep":50,"LoadAvg":19,"POWER":"OFF","Wifi":{"AP":1,"SSId":"*************","BSSId":"*************","Channel":11,"RSSI":52,"LinkCount":36,"Downtime":"0T00:02:31"}}
2019-08-20T00:26:43.689504+02:00 KitchenLight ESP-RSL: SENSOR = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:44","AM2301":{"Temperature":27.7,"Humidity":59.4},"TempUnit":"C"}
2019-08-20T00:26:45.229894+02:00 BathroomFan ESP-RSL: STATE = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:44","Uptime":"3T22:28:27","Vcc":3.141,"SleepMode":"Dynamic","Sleep":50,"LoadAvg":19,"POWER":"OFF","Wifi":{"AP":1,"SSId":"*************","BSSId":"*************","Channel":11,"RSSI":84,"LinkCount":28,"Downtime":"0T00:04:17"}}
2019-08-20T00:26:45.229894+02:00 BathroomFan ESP-RSL: SENSOR = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:44","AM2301":{"Temperature":27.7,"Humidity":64.1},"TempUnit":"C"}
2019-08-20T00:26:51.960401+02:00 EntranceLight ESP-RSL: STATE = {"Time":"2019-08-19T23:26:52","Uptime":"3T03:20:28","Heap":14,"SleepMode":"Dynamic","Sleep":50,"LoadAvg":19,"POWER":"OFF","Wifi":{"AP":1,"SSId":"*************","BSSId":"*************","Channel":11,"RSSI":100,"LinkCount":19,"Downtime":"0T00:01:40"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` with options `-P` (Perl)  and `-o` (Only matches):

```
grep -Po '"LoadAvg":\d+,"POWER":"[^"]+"' file.txt
"LoadAvg":19,"POWER":"OFF"
"LoadAvg":19,"POWER":"OFF"
"LoadAvg":19,"POWER":"OFF"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you intent to use pure linux (e.g sed, grep) or some language to do it? I think in most of languages you could use named groups like:

```
\"LoadAvg\":(?P<loadAvg>\d+?),\"POWER\":\"(?P<power>.+?)\"
```